# блокировка записи на время

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, как правильно реализовать блокировку записи в `MySQL`.

Ситуация - есть некоторая страница, куда выводятся новые заявки для операторов. Страница из двух `div`. Первый `div` - выведенные номера новых заказов, при нажатии на номер заказа ajax'ом подтягивается вся информация по нему во второй `div`. Оператор может отредактировать некоторые поля.

Не могу понять, каким образом можно заблокировать подтянутую запись на то время, пока её просматривает другой регистратор?

Comment: А если закрыли браузер без сохранения редактирования? Или обрыв связи? И запись заблокировалась навечно :)

Comment: Ну например при получении записи сразу в спец поле в ней отмечать id получившего оператора. А других предупреждать, что запись вроде как открыта другим. Но именно "вроде как", как правильно заметил Visman она может оказаться за оператором навечно. Даже если вы будете отслеживать как то что браузер еще открыт, случаи "открыл запись и пошел пить кофе" - нормальная рабочая ситуация

Comment: Об данных вариантах я думал :) Но пока не имею представления как это можно реализовать. Как вариант записывать ID записи в сессию и при выборе другой заявки снимать блокировку с просмотренной ранее.

Comment: Так что лучше решать задачу технологически. для начала узнать откуда оператор берет новые значения для полей, которые он редактирует, если сам придумывает - у вас проблема. Если же берет например с какого нибудь бумажного документа - то обеспечить что бы документы относящиеся к одной записи физически не могли попасть к разным операторам одновременно

Comment: Операторы обрабатывают заявки,которые поступают с сайта. Предполагается одновременная работа более 1 оператора. В принципе как вариант я думаю можно использовать дополнительное поле, куда будет вносится id оператора. ТК у заявки есть статус и временные рамки на обработку можно повесить на скрипт проверку блокировки, если более 10 минут заявка заблокирована и статус не изменен, то блокировка снимается.

Comment: Ну да, как то так, отслеживать свободных операторов и назначать заявку следующему свободному оператору, отметив его id в заявке и возможно поставив соответствующий статус. И оператор должен закончить назначенную заявку или в случае форс-мажора нажать кнопку, что не может окончить. И да, какой то механизм на случай если кнопки забыли нажать. например что бы какой то менеджер мог следить за процессом и по крайней мере имел права в ручную перекинуть заявку.

Comment: как в системах электронных очередей, оператор жмет кнопку "готов обрабатывать заявку". Если он пошел на обед он соответственно кнопку не нажимает или уходя на обед нажимает что ушел или выходит из системы

Comment: В принципе можно предусмотреть отсылку keep-alive с операторского места раз в минуту и получать подтверждение от сервера. Если в течении 5 минут не получено ни одного подтверждения от сервера, то прекращать обработку заявки на стороне оператора, а еще через пару минут снимать блокировку

Comment: Возможно сделать связующую таблицу заявка-оператор. причем что бы оба поля в таблице были уникальными. тогда одна заявка сможет физически находится строго у одного оператора. И у одного оператора будет строго не более 1 заявки. Собственно наличие записей в этой таблице и считать "блокировкой", при желании навесить туда дату постановки в очередь и прочие интересные поля

Comment: В общем использовать конструкции типа SELECT FOR UPDATE не желательно, лучше использовать промежуточные таблицы с проверкой статусов и изменений.

Answer (score 2):

У заявки должно быть свойство "занята" и кем.

При открытии заявки первым оператором у заявки внутри транзакции устанавливается это свойство. В таком случае никакой другой оператор не сможет в то же время установить эту отметку у этой же записи. Другие записи будут свободны для изменений.

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id = ? FOR UPDATE;
-- проверяем что заявка не занята кем-то другим
UPDATE requests SET taken = 1 WHERE id = ?;
COMMIT;
```

Освобождение заявок можно делать как по переходу со страницы:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    /* запрос на освобождение заявки */
});
```

Так и в фоновом режиме по тайм-ауту. Можно ещё поставить на самой странице какой-то таймер, который будет освобождать заявку по неактивности оператора.

---

Другим вариантом может быть [блокировка всей таблицы от записи с помощью команды `LOCK TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html). Этот вариант менее предпочтительный так как в момент изменений никто другой ничего не сможет делать с другими рядами, в то время как защита нужна только для одного ряда.

(Два дефиса - это [обычный формат комментария](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html), не ошибка.)

Answer (score 0):

> Если ты боишься **коллизий**, то вряд ли ты их сможешь поймать.

Можно сделать так: Загружая заявку для оператора, проверяем время последнего изменения. Пускаем аякс через каждые 5 секунд проверять время последнего изменения и айдишник оператора.

Если время изменилось, а другой оператор уже начал редактирование, то выскакивает **алярма** с текстом, например:

> Только что Евлампия изменила эту заявку. Загрузить? Сохранить ваше сообщение.

Оператор нажимает **ок**, его текст копируется в буфер, заявка обновляется, затем он либо добавляет свои исправления, либо уходит из этой заявки.

> Для информативности, можно еще говорить оператору, если кто-то кроме него смотрит эту заявку.